# SQL - JOIN if specific column contains data matching two others

Tags: sql

I've got two tables set up kind of like so:

```
table1
id   | firstName  | lastName  
-----|------------|-----------  
01   | john       | smith
02   | dick       | johnson
03   | sam        | adams
04   | tiberius   | kirk

table2  
fullName            | status
--------------------|---------
john smith          | active
dick arnold johnson | active
samuel adams        | disabled
jim tiberius        | active
```

I need to get the status column from table2 into table1. The issue though is that names in both tables don't match exactly (as I've sort of demonstrated). I would like to keep all entries in table1, even if it can't match them to an entry in table2. Ultimately, I would like my output to be something like this:

```
id   | firstName  | lastName  | fullName            | status
-----|------------|-----------|---------------------|--------
01   | john       | smith     | john smith          | active
02   | dick       | johnson   | dick arnold johnson | active
03   | sam        | adams     | samuel adams        | disabled
04   | tiberius   | kirk      | NULL                | NULL
```

I've been trying to figure out how to do this with a LEFT JOIN but I'm extremely new to SQL and have had trouble figuring out 1) what to join them on if there's no common column between table1 and table2 and 2) how do I get it to try to find fullName AND lastName in fullName and only join entries when it matches both?

Comment: Are you sure there is no other way to get a true identity match between table 1 and 2?  If not you might be stuck having to use some fuzzy logic (SOUNDEX, perhaps) to infer the relationship, but you're not going to be guaranteed to have a match be 100% accurate

Comment: @Blindy, I'm using an internally developed tool that uses SQL to run queries so I don't think it qualifies as any of the common types. My understanding of that could be totally wrong, though.

Comment: @BradD, I won't be able to get a straight match between the two tables so this will definitely rely on fuzzy logic. That was the expectation going in though so it's ok that it won't be 100% accurate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Left outer joins take all rows of the first table along with rows of the second table, even if there is no matching row in the second table.

For exact matches, you can use:

```
select * from table1 left outer join table2 on firstName || ' ' || lastName = fullName
```

in Oracle.

```
select * from table1 left outer join table2 on concat_ws(' ', firstName, lastName) = fullName
```

in MySql.

For partial matches, for example:

```
select * from table1 left outer join table2 on fullName like firstName || '%' and fullName like '%' || lastName
```

in Oracle.

```
select * from table1 left outer join table2 on fullName like concat(firstName, '%') and fullName like concat('%', lastName)
```

There are more complicated queries you can use inside the "text" packages of your DB.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd do it in T-SQL:

```
select *
from table1
  left outer join table2 on name like fname+'%' and name like '%'+lname
```

You can see it in action here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/10469/1/0

Because T-SQL doesn't have a `regexp` operator that's pretty much the best you can do. You can use word boundary regexes in MySql for example, but the main idea is the same.